# how to store os.execute as variable

Tags: curl, lua

I am writing in Lua script that requires a long curl to be executed.  I need the curl command value to be stored in a variable.  It seem trivial, but I cant seem to figure this one out.  Yes I know that I could use some curl modules and whatnot.  The problem is that this is for an older equipment and for some reason it doesn't work with any of the builtin curl modules, so I am executing the curl command as is.

```
command = "'https://mylongurl/value1?value2=somevalue&value3=someothervalue'"

result os.execute("curl " ..command)

print(result)

--this prints "true/false"
--I need the actual result
```

Comment: Use `io.popen()` to read the stdout

Comment: also you can retirect stdout/stderr to temp files and read them after command done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Egor Skriptunoff mentioned:

```
Use io.popen() to read the stdout
```